# RPi 3 blinking Red and Green light

Tags: pi-3

I have a couple of RPI which I use regularly. Recently, I have been seeing Red and Green light blinking on my RPi. Rpi works great. I just couldn't understand why both the lights are blinking as it should be red constant and green blinking on a normal scenario. Just wondering if anyone has faced the same issue.

Comment: Your power supply is inadequate. See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)
The Pi itself will work with low voltage, but peripherals may not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most common causes of your problem are an inadequate power supply or an SD card that isn't written properly, or isn't functioning properly.

Comment: It was a power issue. I got it solved by changing the adapter.

Comment: @dastaan glad to hear that